# How to Concatenate few rows into one single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Let's assume that I have one table with two columns A and B. In A column I have number for example 1,2,3. In B column I have some characters (not the special ones). It looks like this :

```
Column A: 1   1   2   2   3

Column B: a   b   c   d   e
```

My desired output would be :

```
Column A: 1      2   3
Column B: a-b   c-d  e
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select a, min(b) + '-' + max(b)
from t
group by a;
```